# ARCore - Sceneform - popup view on top of Supermarket product

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

how can i display a custom view near a supermarket product using SceneForm.

Most sample display the object on a plane surface.
Is there anyway to display  it near a certain position with a fixed height and width ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check out [Augmented Images API](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/augmented-images) from ARCore. You can place your virtual object on a corner of a target image.